# how to update filtered list view by binding filterProperty to certain value

Tags: ember.js

I have a list which based on certain properties returns a sub list. Is it possible to bind this property with outside control, so when it is set, the filtered list view can refresh itself.

Right now if I do:

`MyApp.widgetIconsController.set 'iconareacolor', 'lightBlue'`

the filtered list didn't change

```
{{#each MyApp.widgetIconsController.filtered}} 
    {{#view MyApp.IconView txtBinding ="this"}}
      <div> {{unbound txt.widgetName}} </div>
    {{/view}}
 {{/each}} 

MyApp.widgetIconsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create
  iconareacolor: null

  content: [
    MyApp.ButtonWidget.create({'theme': 'lightblue'}),
    MyApp.TextWidget.create({'theme': 'lightblue'}),
    MyApp.ButtonWidget.create({'theme': 'lightcoral'}),
    MyApp.TextWidget.create({'theme': 'lightcoral'}),
    MyApp.InputWidget.create({'theme': 'lightcoral'}) ]

  filtered: (->
    filteredList = this.get("content").filterProperty 'theme', this.get('iconareacolor')
  ).property("content.@each.theme").cacheable()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add iconareacolor to the filtered property list.

`.property("content.@each.theme", "iconareacolor")`

Comment: add iconareacolor to property list didn't fix the issue, i post a demo [http://jsfiddle.net/lily/AR7Kr/](http://jsfiddle.net/lily/AR7Kr/), when you click the text 'blue' or 'red', it suppose display a filtered list

Comment: I spelt it 'colour' and you've spelt it 'color'. International English vs British English causing problems yet again. Have updated my answer and the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tomwhatmore/AR7Kr/1/

Comment: finally figured out,  instead of using Ember.ArrayProxy.create, have to use Ember.ArrayController.create, here is the working demo [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/lily/jcpAs/)

Comment: @lilyfrommars `ArrayProxy` and `ArrayController` are exactly the same, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071570/whats-the-purpose-of-arraycontroller-and-arrayproxy) for details. The only problem was the fact I spelt color with a u, as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I gave you a +1 since the OP couldn't be bothered to accept your answer =/